# Not able to connect to Snowflake database with snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

**I am not able to connect with snowsql by Windows console:**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    C:\Users\musik>snowsql -a [myAccount] -u [myUserName]<br>
    Installing version: 1.2.0  [####################################]  100%<br>
    Password:<br>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

**I get this error message:**

```
250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: [myAccount].snowflakecomputing.com:443. HTTP 403: Forbidden
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgKlG.png)

Then I used `-o log_level=DEBUG`. In the log file I can see that I am getting a "forbidden" error:

```
2019-12-05 16:45:16,510 (6472/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:822  - HTTP 403: Forbidden. Retrying...
```

What can I do? Has somebody the same issue?

Comment: Be sure to include the region and such in your account.  It should include everything up to the snowflakecomputing.com in the URL that you use to access Snowflake through the UI.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your hint. The command (in my case) must look like this:  
  
`snowsql -a [myAccount].west-europe.azure -u [myUserName]`

Comment: @MikeWalton You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment earlier: Be sure to include the region and such in your account. It should include everything up to the snowflakecomputing.com in the URL that you use to access Snowflake through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command:

```
snowflake URL : https://abc.snowflakecomputing.com
Account_name  : abc
User_name     : Give fully qualified user name

snowsql -a <account_name> -u <user_name>
```

Note: Prior to this ensure you are able to login with user name and password using snowflake Web UI.